# Adding Google Drive to Windows Explorer Interface

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

### Editing Windows Explorer Interface

This is the interface I am referring to:
[image: Windows Explorer]

I would like to have under the OneDrive link a Google Drive link, now it is a subfolder of Quick Access. I want to be able to click directly at it, just like the OneDrive link. I have no idea on how to do this, so I would like the help.

This is how I would like to have it. (this is done through editing the previous screenshot)
[image: Desired Version]